# Screen startup apps

Tags: command-line, gnu-screen

I know that most people don't bother with things like screen anymore, but I happen to really like it, even in this GUI day and age. I still do most of my development from a BASH prompt, so it's extremely useful to me.

What I'm wondering is what the easiest way is to start an instance of screen (stored in a shell script or .screenrc or somewhere else) so that it starts up with set commands already running in set windows. For example, I use a django test server, so I'd like one window to come up running "python manage.py runserver" and another blank, waiting for commands. The man page is wholly indecipherable. These old unix utilities can do quite nearly everything, so I'm sure this is possible, but I can't for the life of me figure out how. I

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add to your .screenrc lines like this:

```
screen -t title command to execute
```

Each line as above will create a window executing the specified command inside screen.

Comment: [an answer on another question](http://superuser.com/questions/136621/i-am-not-seeing-named-session-in-gnu-screen/136672#136672) shows a good example .screenrc snippet.  apparently you can include the window number between the *title* and *command*, and use *select* to pick which one to show on startup.